# Assigning and using protocol-typed variable to a member of a class

Tags: ios, swift, interface, delegates

I was reading the code of a good tutorial, when I found something I don't understand too well (the full code is here: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/ConnectedColors.zip):

```
protocol ColorServiceManagerDelegate {

 func connectedDevicesChanged(_ manager : ColorServiceManager, connectedDevices: [String])
 func colorChanged(_ manager : ColorServiceManager, colorString: String)

}

class ColorServiceManager : NSObject {

 fileprivate let ColorServiceType = "example-color"
 fileprivate let myPeerId = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
 fileprivate let serviceAdvertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser
 fileprivate let serviceBrowser : MCNearbyServiceBrowser

 // THIS ONE!
 var delegate : ColorServiceManagerDelegate?

 override init() {

    self.serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: myPeerId, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: ColorServiceType)
    self.serviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: myPeerId, serviceType: ColorServiceType)

    super.init()

    // AND THIS
    self.serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
    self.serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()

    // AND THIS
    self.serviceBrowser.delegate = self
    self.serviceBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
    }
```

What I don't understand is:

1. why the developer declares this delegate variable;
2. why it is an optional;
3. why is it of the type of the protocol;
4. why the compiler doesn't complain about serviceAdvertiser and serviceBrowser having no delegate property;
5. what he accomplishes by assigning this delegate to self;

Just to name a few   :-)

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. What you're seeing are three instances of the Delegation pattern. [Have a look here to get started](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276). As to question 4: These are three different `delegate` properties. If you look at the [`MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity/mcnearbyserviceadvertiser) class you will see that it has its own `delegate` property

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but when I tried to comment out the delegate variable I received three errors and I thought they were related to those because I don't see any other assignment in the class (or, better, just another one, that makes three errors)

Comment: Ok, @Arthur, now I understand it better: errors are elsewhere (in another file, where they assign the delegate in a viewcontroller) and in an extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. delegates and protocols in ios are used for callbacks just like interfaces in java if you are familiar with java programming language. So a protocol contains some methods which needs to be implemented by all the classes that confirm to that protocol and the delegate variable is used to call those methods from the above mentioned protocol.
2. The delegate variables are generally optionals because there might be a case where no object confirms to the protocol and the delegate variable could be nil.
3. Delegates are used to call the methods from protocols so it is necessary that it be the type of the protocol
4. If all the non optional methods in swift are initialised in the init before calling super.init() then the compiler has no problems
5. By assigning delegate to self the object declares that it implements ColorServiceManagerDelegate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I answer the 5th: so, why he doesn't do `class ColorServiceManager : NSObject, ColorServiceManagerDelegate` ?

Comment: he has done that in extension check out this line of code extension ColorServiceManager : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate just below the class definition

Comment: Meantime, thanks to you and @Arthur I found an interesting thing in the other file: what I had not mentally connected was the delegate in the viewController viewDidLoad and the delegate we're talking about. I always used "predefined" delegates, I had never seen a custom one, so I'm investigating further. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.